# what this type of if arguments evaluates in PHP? if(!a=foo()) { //code}

Tags: php

I am not able understand below mentioned code. in if conditional both assignment and negate operators are used. if anyone explains me this i will be very much thankful to you.

```
<?php
function foo() {
return mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
}

function start(){
    if(!$con=foo()){
    exit();
    }
return $con;
}
?>
```

Comment: It means that `foo()` is assigned to `a` and `negate` tells us that if it returns false

Comment: that means if my mysqli connection is not successful, then if condition will be true?

Comment: I think u cannot do `function foo() = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');` in PHP

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how did you initialize function

Comment: None of what you've written is valid PHP. I would recommend going through some tutorials and the manual (http://php.net).

Comment: Sorry, but your "code" is not valid php. You should not post questions like "please explain to me what this does", as this is not a coding school. SOF is for people seeking help to solve a real, concrete problem.

Comment: i had done this

Comment: You have done what? As we've pointed out, this is all invalid code so the question what the if-expression means is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php we don't initialize functions like variables. We can define function in this way

```
function foo() {
 $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
 return $connection; // it will return true or false on the basis of mysqli_connect() function
}
if(!$a =foo()) { //The negate in if tells us if it is not returning true 
//code goes here
}
```

Comment: Actually, you should assign `foo()` to a variable and check that. If you don't, you will create a new connection every single time you're calling `foo()`. Alternatively, set `static $connection;` in your function and only create the connection if it's empty.

Comment: Hmm, Good point..

Comment: i changed code and its working fine. many thanks to Zain Farooq and Magnus Eriksson.

Comment: @Zain farooq. i am reading code like this. foo() returns mysqli_connect. if connection is not successful then it returns false and by negate sign it becomes boolean TRUe and first curly bracket code exit() is executed. but if connection is successful then 'if statement' simply returns connection resource.. Right?

Comment: @aaa123123 Yes...